# pi2 stopped working

Tags: boot, power, pi-2

I have a pi2 Model B v1.1 which has been working fine for the last few months. I have 2 micro SD cards, one with raspian on and the other openElec with XBMC. Yesterday they both worked, today, neither does. When I connect power, the TV via the HDMI doesn't display at all, but there is life via the flashing lights.

Using the OpenElec SD card I get:

```
solid red - green flickering
red pulses -green flickering
solid red - light green flickering
occasional red blip.
```

Using the Raspian SD card I get:

```
solid red - light green flickering
occasional green blip.
```

I thought that it may be power supply related after following [R-Pi troubleshooting guide](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems), as the red light was blinking, so...

1. I checked the power supply voltage from the Pi2 (underside PP1 + input housing)and it read 4.92v (sounds fine right?)
2. I used a totally different power supply and different cable (no difference)
3. I thought I might have corrupted the SD cards, so have just re-imaged the Raspian with the latest version 3.18. No Joy.
4. I edited the config.txt file on the new raspian image and added all configurations in "No HDMI output at all". But no luck

   - hdmi_safe=1
   - config_hdmi_boost=4
   - hdmi_force_hotplug=1
   - hdmi_group=2
   - hdmi_mode=4

I think I have bricked my Pi2. Help! Does anyone have any other insight?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to check if RPi is working or not is to burn a fresh `Raspbian` in an SD card (brand new SD card if possible), powering it up via laptop / desktop USB (do not use Hub) or a decent (with current rating 1A or more) charger. Don't connect any USB peripherals to RPi. Just connect TV / monitor via HDMI and give it a go. If it doesn't show up anything in display, it is most certain that something is wrong with RPi.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interestingly I have started it with the LAN cable plugged in. The lights on the LAN port are flickering and I've checked the router and can see the pi being allocated an IP address. Apparently this means the boot is happening. The display should happen before the LAN is started but it's not...

Comment: @sarin Can you ssh into that IP ? `ssh pi@<pi-ip>`, password : `raspberry` ?

Comment: nope. Pi is going back to the oven. ;(

Comment: @sarin So, it didn't work :(

Comment: It's possible the power supply \ cable i was using which was having problems and causing brownouts bricked the board...

Comment: sent it back to modmypi and they replaced it. Its working now! Must have burnt something out....

Comment: @sarin Good that they replaced it. :)